# Error 405 (Method not Allowed) al intentar editar un campo en la base de datos. ¿Como lo puedo solucionar? laravel 5.7

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, laravel

mi situación es la siguiente

```html
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
 <meta name="_token" content="{{csrf_token()}}" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/style.css')}}">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
 <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
 <section class="container mt-5 pt-5"> 
  <ol class="breadcrumb">
   <li class="breadcrumb-item active"><a href="{{ route('administrador')}}">Perfil</a></li>
   <li class="breadcrumb-item active"><a href="{{ route('mostrarUsuarios', Auth::user())}}"> Usuarios </a></li>
   <li class="breadcrumb-item active"> Ver Solicitudes</li>
   <li class="breadcrumb-item active"><a href="{{ route('reportes')}}">Ver Registros del Sistema</a></li>
  </ol>
  <h1 class="page-header" align="center">SOLICITUDES</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="tablaSolicitudes">
       <table class="table table-bordered" style="align:center" id="tablaAdministrador">
        <thead>
         <tr>
          <th>Numero de Solicitud</th>
          <th>Unidad Solicitante</th>
          <th>Usuario</th>
          <th>Estado de Solicitud</th>
          <th>Ver Solicitud</th>
          <th>Editar</th>
         </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach($administradores as $administrador)
          <form method="post" name="formEstado" id="formEstado" action="{{ route('ejecutarSolicitud',$administrador->id)}}">
           {{csrf_field() }}
           {{method_field('PATCH')}}
           <tr>
            <td>{{$administrador['id']}}</td>
            <td>{{$administrador['UnidadSolicitante']}}</td>
            @foreach($usuarios as $usuario)
             @if($administrador->user_id == $usuario->id)
              <td>{{$usuario['name']}}</td>
             @endif
            @endforeach
            <td>{{$administrador->estadoSolicitud}}</td>
            <td><a href="{{ route('VerSolicitudAdministrador', $administrador->id)}}" class="btn btn-primary">Ver Solicitud</a></td>
            @if($administrador->estadoSolicitud == 'Pendiente')
             <td>Esta solicitud esta pendiente</td>
            @endif
            @if($administrador->estadoSolicitud == 'Rechazada')
              <td>No se puede modificar una Solicitud Rechazada</td>
            @endif 
            @if($administrador->estadoSolicitud == 'Compra Realizada')
             <td>Esta compra ya se realizó</td>
            @endif
            @if($administrador->estadoSolicitud != 'Rechazada')
             @if($administrador->estadoSolicitud != 'Compra Realizada')
              @if($administrador->estadoSolicitud == 'Anulada')
               <td>
                <select name="estado" class="custom-select" id="estado">
                 <option value="Compra En Ejecucion" class="form-control">Compra en Ejecucion</option>
                 <option value="Compra Realizada" class="form-control">Compra Realizada</option>
                </select>
                <button class="btn btn-warning" onclick="editarEstado()">Editar</button>
               </td>
              @endif
              @if($administrador->estadoSolicitud == 'Compra En Ejecucion')
               <td>
                <select name="estado" class="custom-select" id="estado">
                 <option value="Compra Realizada" class="form-control">Compra Realizada</option>
                 <option value="Anulada" class="form-control">Compra Anulada</option>
                </select>
                <button class="btn btn-warning" onclick="editarEstado()">Editar</button>
               </td>
              @endif
              @if($administrador->estadoSolicitud == 'Aprobada')
               <td>
                <select name="estado" class="custom-select" id="estado">
                 <option value="Compra Realizada" class="form-control">Compra Realizada</option>
                 <option value="Compra En Ejecucion" class="form-control">Compra en Ejecucion</option>
                 <option value="Anulada" class="form-control">Compra Anulada</option>
                </select>
                <button class="btn btn-warning" onclick="editarEstado()">Editar</button>
               </td>
              @endif
             @endif
            @endif
           </tr>
          </form>
        @endforeach
        </tbody>
       </table>
    </div>
   </div>
 </section>
```

Y este es el javascript

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#tablaAdministrador').dataTable();
  });
  
 window.onload = function(){
  $.ajaxSetup({
   headers : {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
   }
  });
 }
 function editarEstado()
 {
  swal({
   title: 'Espera un momento!',
   text: 'Trabajando tu solicitud..',
   allowOutsideClick: false,
   allowEscapeKey: false,
   allowEnterKey: false,
   onOpen: () => {
    swal.showLoading()
   }
  })
  $.ajax({
   headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
   },
   type: "POST",
   data: $('#formEstado').serialize(),
   url: "{{ url('/TablaSolicitudesAdministrador')}}",
   success: function(response){
    if(response =! 1)
    {
     console.log(response);
    }
    else
    {
     window.location.href = "{{ url('/PerfilAdministrador')}}";
    }
   }
  });
 }
  
</script>
```

Y aquí el controlador que realiza la modificación

```
    public function editarEstado(Request $request, $id)
{
    $solicitud = \App\SolicitudDeVentas::find($id);
    if($request->estado != NULL)
    {
        $solicitud->estadoSolicitud = $request->estado;
    }
    $user = \App\User::find($solicitud->user_id);
    $email = $user->email;
    if($solicitud->estadoSolicitud == 'Compra En Ejecucion')
    {
        \Mail::to($email)->send(new SolicitudEnProceso());
    }
    if($solicitud->estadoSolicitud == 'Compra Realizada')
    {
        \Mail::to($email)->send(new SolicitudRealizada());
    }
    if($solicitud->estadoSolicitud == 'Anulada')
    {
        \Mail::to($email)->send(new SolicitudAnulada());
    }

    $solicitud->save();
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Lo que sucede que al momento que quiero editar el estado de la solicitud (haciendo clic en el botón "Editar") no hace absolutamente nada. ¿Alguna idea de lo que pueda estar pasando?. De antemano Muchas Gracias.

**UPDATE**

Aqui estan las rutas definidas.

```
Route::get('/TablaSolicitudesAdministrador','PerfilAdministradorController@mostrarTabla')->middleware('is_admin')->name('administradorTabla');
Route::patch('/TablaSolicitudesAdministrador/{id}','PerfilAdministradorController@editarEstado')->middleware('is_admin')->name('ejecutarSolicitud');
```

Cuando ejecuto `php artisan route:list` Aparecen las rutas de esta manera

```
|        | GET|HEAD | TablaSolicitudesAdministrador      | administradorTabla        | App\Http\Controllers\PerfilAdministradorController@mostrarTabla        | web,is_admin,auth       |

|        | PATCH    | TablaSolicitudesAdministrador/{id} | ejecutarSolicitud         | App\Http\Controllers\PerfilAdministradorController@editarEstado        | web,is_admin,auth
```

Aquí se muestra cuando salta el error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De antemano muchas gracias.

**UPDATE 2**

La solucion de Fran me elimino el error 405, pero me salta este otro. Al clickear el boton 'Editar' parece ser que no se recibe un "response" por lo tanto me redirige al perfil y no me realiza el cambio.

```
if(response =! 1)
            {
                console.log(response);
            }
            else
            {
                window.location.href = "{{ url('/PerfilAdministrador')}}";
            }
```

Eso quiere decir que no entra al primer 'if'.
HTTP Trace me tira el siguiente error.

```
    HTTP/1.1 302 Found
 Redirect to: http://localhost:8000/TablaSolicitudesAdministrador
Host: localhost:8000
Date: Wed, 20 Feb 2019 15:41:44 +0000
Connection: close
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.10
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Date: Wed, 20 Feb 2019 15:41:44 GMT
Location: http://localhost:8000/TablaSolicitudesAdministrador
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Comment: Podrias instalar el laravel/debugbar para ayudarte a saber que está pasando, o puedes ver los logs de error también (en la carpeta storage). Si sigue sin mostrar nada y si estás en chrome abre developer tools > revisa si hay algún mensaje en la consola o busca en las pestañas la opcion network (no se como diga en español), ahi verás las direcciones y si hay errores la herramienta te los dira (402, 422, 403..).

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder. Lo intentare y aviso que es lo que pasa.

Comment: Lo que me salio en la consola del navegador, cuando intento editar el estado es esto. jquery.min.js:4 POST http://localhost:8000/TablaSolicitudesAdministrador 405 (Method Not Allowed). No se como arreglarlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que no has definido correctamente la ruta. Tienes un **get** y un **patch**. Pero no veo una ruta **post** en tu ejemplo. Deberías agregar algo así:

```
Route::post('/TablaSolicitudesAdministrador','PerfilAdministradorController@editarEstado')->middleware('is_admin')->name('ejecutarSolicitud');
```

**Editado**

El problema con el error 500 ya es un problema interno del servidor. Es decir, ahora está encontrando la ruta pero hay un error en el código. En la ruta que te puse anteriormente no está recibiendo ningún "id" por esto puede ser el error. Para ello vamos a editarla, dejándola así:

```
Route::post('/TablaSolicitudesAdministrador/{id}','PerfilAdministradorController@editarEstado')->middleware('is_admin')->name('ejecutarSolicitud');
```

Para que esto funcione, también debes editar tu consulta ajax agregando este paramento a la ruta. Algo así:

```
$.ajax({
        ...
            url: "{{ url('/TablaSolicitudesAdministrador')}}/"+ID,
```